# Apache second instance installation rights

Tags: apache

I've installed a second apache instance in a linux box (CentOS 6.6) as a regular user
  (non-root) with sudo rights.
  Although the apache installation completed successfully , when i browsed the installation
  path :

```
/usr/local/apache2
```

the owner is root and not the non-root user that i used for the whole   process.

```
 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Sep  20 11:42 bin
 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  5096 Sep  20 11:42 build
 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  6096 Sep 20 10:43 cgi-bin
 drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  6096 Sep 20 14:13 conf
 drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  6096 Jul 28 10:43 error
 drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  6096 Mar  2  2010 htdocs
 drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  28096 Sep 20 10:43 icons
 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  1096 Sep 20 11:42 include
 drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  5096 Sep 20 11:42 lib
 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  7096 Sep 20 14:41 logs
 drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Sep 20 10:43 man
 drwxrwxr-x 14 root root 10480 Sep 20  2010 manual
 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  2096 Jul 28 10:43 modules
```

Any ideas why this is happening ?
 Also if i change the ownership of the whole directory tree to non-root user, will apache still be operational and stable ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Every command you type with `sudo` is executed as root